# Angular4: Disable button in ngFor after click

Tags: angular, button, ngfor, disable

I have a `<button>` in a ngFor loop and I want it to be disabled after the user clicks on the button. There is a button for each element of the loop so I have to differentiate them using a different boolean value for each of them.

Here is a code snippet from the html:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let i of items">
    <button type="button" [disabled]="'btn' + i.id" (click)="btn + i.id=true">TEST</button>
<div>
```

The `[disabled]="'btn' + i.id"` part seems to work, but i cant set the value of it to `true` using `(click)="btn + i.id=true"`. How can I concatenate the `btn` and `i.id` and set the value of it to true?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code from head (can have bugs):

In your .ts component use array:

```
buttons = Array(10).fill(false); // e.g. 10 = size of items
```

In your template:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let i of items; index as j">
    <button type="button" [disabled]="buttons[j]" (click)="buttons[j]=true">TEST</button>
<div>
```

The `index as j` works on Angular 5/6, for lower version use `let j=index`

### Alternative solution

Add to items field disabled and use that field directly:

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="item.disabled" (click)="item.disabled=true">TEST</button>
```

Comment: Τhanks! Works just like I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

> Analyze below code

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let i of items">
  <button type="button" [disabled]="item.clicked" (click)="item.clicked=true">TEST</button>
<div>
```

> This is how it should be implemented in Angular.
>
> If you want to know which button gets clicked in your component. Then add **'clicked'**
>   property in **items** array and then use it in the component.