# Angular 2+ disabling button of a particular row

Tags: javascript, html, angular, button, disable

I am trying to disable the button after a add button has been clicked. 
For sake of simplicity I am not adding details just the code that is cause the issue.

```
<div *ngFor="let n of records">
   <span>{{n.name}}</span>
   <span>{{n.location}}</span>
   <button (click)="addtomainrecord(n)" [disabled]="disablebutton">add</button>
</div>
```

In my component I have declared

```
  disablebutton:boolean=false;
   //later in my code
  addtomainrecord(record) {
     this.disablebutton=true;
   //rest of the code follows
  }
```

The issue I am facing is that once I click add button first time, all the buttons are disabled, while I want to just disable the button of row that I just clicked.

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a the "ownership" for `records` array, you can add an other key-value pair, say 'disabled', otherwise you can create a parallel array `disablebutton` of the same length as records:

```
  disablebutton = [false,false,...] // better be done in a for loop or with array methods in your code
```

In the template, you should pass the id of the row which needs the button to be disabled. You get the row index in ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let n of records; let i = index">
   <span>{{n.name}}</span>
   <span>{{n.location}}</span>
   <button (click)="addtomainrecord(i)" [disabled]="disablebutton[i]">add</button>
</div>
```

And the the method will catch that index to set the button state:

```
  addtomainrecord(index) {
    this.disablebutton[index] = true;
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nr31ct)

Comment: If you need more detail on creating and using the key-value pair in records, comment me :)

Comment: Thank you I got it to work using your solution. All solution looked good yours required no change in my object.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a new property to each item of array and check this property for disable item:

Component.ts

```
myArray:Array<{firstName:string,lastName}>=[]; // there isn't isDisabled in this model

doSomething(item){
   item.isDisabled=true;
   // do something
}
```

Component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myArray">
   <button (click)="doSomething(item)" [disabled]="item.isDisabled">Register</button>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will work

```
<div *ngFor="let n of records">
   <span>{{n.name}}</span>
   <span>{{n.location}}</span>
   <button (click)="addtomainrecord(n)" [disabled]="n.disablebutton">add</button>
</div>


addtomainrecord(record) {,
     record.disablebutton=true;
   //rest of the code follows
}
```

For reference: [Disable button with ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276941/angular4-disable-button-in-ngfor-after-click)